# Android layout code not displaying in Stack Overflow post

Tags: support, specific-question, code-formatting, android-app

Can someone help me to edit [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41563918/smaller-down-the-image-source-inside-imageview/41564295)? I don't understand why my Android layout is not displaying in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Android layout code is inside a *Bulleted List*. I have indented each code line by 8 spaces and now it appears correctly. 4 spaces to make it a code block and further spaces to make it a part of bulleted list.